# How to order execution of controller test classes in Junit5 / spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, junit

In my entities I have bidirectional one-to-many relation and I would like to write integration tests with mock.mvc. However, before adding parent, I cannot add child. For this reason, I would like to order my test **classes** like first run AirportControllerTest, secondly RouteControllerTest and lastly FlightController.

Is it possible, or how to handle such case ?

Answer (score 1):

For this specific problem, a hierachical order is better than a sequential order.

If you are using JUnit 5, you can use @Nested tests. https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-nested

Nest your Test classes in a way that the Parent Test class runs first and the nested Test can use the test objects created by the parent.

Here is a high-level example:

```
class AirportControllerTest{

    @Test
    void testAirportController() {
       //Add parent here
    }

    @Nested
    class RouteControllerTest {
      
        @Test
        void testRouteController() {
           //Use test objects from parent here
        }
        @Nested
        class FlightControllerTest{
      
           @Test
           void testFlightController() {
              //Use test objects from AirportControllerTest & RouteControllerTest 
            }
    }
}
```

If you are using JUnit 4, you can enclose your Test Classes in a Test Suite. This answer is a good match - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42600619/6352160

**Less relevant:** For configuring the **Test Method** order within a Test Class.

If you are using JUnit5, specify @TestMethodOrder in your Test class and use @Order annotation on methods to specify their order of execution. Reference - https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestMethodOrder.html.

If using JUnit4, this question has several possible solutions - [How to run test methods in specific order in JUnit4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693626/how-to-run-test-methods-in-specific-order-in-junit4)

Comment: if I am not wrong it orders the test methods inside a class, what I want to do is to order test Classes

Comment: @YektaAnılAksoy I just realized that I read the question wrong. My first answer was for ordering the Test methods. I edited the answer.